# Why did no one stop Harry and Marv from chasing Kevin?

Tags: plot-explanation, home-alone-2-lost-in-new-york

In Home Alone 2, when Harry and Marv are chasing Kevin around New York City, why did no one do anything? Did anyone realize that two grown men are chasing a boy and look like they are trying to abduct him? Surely a Police Officer must have noticed this and wouldn't he or she of stopped them?

Comment: You want an in-universe explanation or a real life explanation? In-universe: Same reason his parents were able to allow him to get lost (or left behind) - twice. Out of universe: People are oblivious and generally don't pay attention or just try to avoid conflict. Confronting the two would be a conflict. Unless Kevin was screaming for help, no one would think anything was wrong enough to intervene. As far as the police, no police were around in those scenes.

Comment: @DustinDavis did you mix up in and out of universe?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 If you're referring to the last statement about the police, it was an after though put in the wrong place.

Comment: @DustinDavis No, I believe BlueMoon is correct. The "people are oblivious..." part is the in-universe explanation. The "Same reason his parents were able to allow him to get lost" part is the out-of-universe explanation.

Comment: My statements are valid (though, they may apply to both in and out). People are oblivious in real life and will avoid conflict until absolutely necessary. However, I don't believe that any parent would accidentally leave their child at home (or in this case get on the wrong plane) and make it all the way to their destination without realizing it In real life, so that fantastical circumstance can only be in-universe.

Comment: @DustinDavis It sounds like you are reversing the 2 definitions. “In-universe” refers to things that make sense within the world that the movie takes place in. It makes sense that people woldnt notice; because that’s what the world is like. It doesn’t make sense that a mother would forget her child (twice). Out-of-universe refers to things related to the making of the movie; such as the fact that the writers needed it to happen in order for there to be a story.